# CLU payload showing incorrect Top Intent with correct intent in the intent list

Tags: json, android-intent

In CLU, I trained an utterance for which top Intent is coming 'None' but inside the intent list it shows the correct intent with the highest confidence score.

What might be the reason the top intent is different from the first element of the array of intents?

Payload:

```
{
    "query": "interruptions",
    "prediction": {
        "topIntent": "None",
        "projectKind": "Conversation",
        "intents": [
            {
                "category": "outages",
                "confidenceScore": 0.6979013
            },
            {
                "category": "faqcategory",
                "confidenceScore": 0.6662484
            },
            {
                "category": "finalstep",
                "confidenceScore": 0.6127817
            },
```

....... and so on

Notice how the top intent is different from the highest scored intent in intents list.

Any idea why this might be the case?

I trained the same utterance 'interruptions' which was giving top Intent as None expecting the result to change, but same response was given.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project setting "None score threshold" value by default it is "0.7". Change this settings to your matching intent (from your example its must be "0.6") and save then Train and Deploy.